# Java score is not increasing with if statements

Tags: java, if-statement, counter

For my java trivia game, I set the questions in the beginning, e.g.

```
if(command.equals("question 1"))
    {
        txtAnswer.setText("");
        q1 = true;
        btnQ1.setEnabled(false);
        lblQuestion.setText("What is 2 + 2?");
        lblOutcome.setText("");
    }
```

and then after all the "if"s for the questions, I have code that verifies if it is correct or not, and if it's correct I increase the score. This is the code I use:

```
if(command.equals("Check")&& (txtAnswer.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("4") && (q1)))
        {
            q1= false;
            lblOutcome.setText("Correct");
            score = score +1;
            lblScore.setText("Current Score: " + score);
            
        }
        else if(command.equals("Check")&& (!txtAnswer.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("4") && (q1)))
        {
            q1= false;
            lblOutcome.setText("Incorrect");
            lblScore.setText("Current Score: " + score);
        
        }
        
        
        
        if(command.equals("Check")&& (txtAnswer.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("8") && (q2)))
        {
            q2= false;
            lblOutcome.setText("Correct");
            score = score +1;
            lblScore.setText("Current Score: " + score);
            
        }
        else if(command.equals("Check")&& (!txtAnswer.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("8") && (q2))
        {
            q2= false;
            lblOutcome.setText("Incorrect");
            lblScore.setText("Current Score: " + score);
            
        }
```

But the problem I'm having right now is that the score is not increasing, it just completely resets to 0 after each question so if I get all the questions right, the score remains at 1. I was wondering what I have to do to fix this?

Edit: this is where wrote the code

```
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        int score = 0;
```

Comment: The answer would depend on where the `score` variable is declared, which you didn't show.

Comment: @Eran sorry about that, I just edited in now!

Comment: @gino, Where did you declared all the "if"s?

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you're initialising your `score` variable inside the action handler. Thus it gets removed and recreated each and every time.

Try declaring it as a class field:

```
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
{
    private int score = 0; 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();
        // int score = 0;  <== remove it from here
```

Comment: ahh!! I see! thank you so much it works now! (sorry my account is really new I tried to upvote but since I'm less than 15 days old it won't show)

Comment: @gino Do not worry about the rep. It's just a number. I'm glad my answer helped you. Welcome to StackOverflow!